# Windows 7 taking 4 minutes to go to sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I'm running Windows 7 x64 on a fast machine with 8GB ram and it takes 4+ minutes to go to sleep. Is this likely just because it's writing 8GB RAM to disk or is there somthing awry?

Comment: To be clear: Are you suspending or hibernating?

Comment: I guess he's hybrid-sleeping.

Comment: that sounds about right for how long it'll take to write 8GB to disk...

Comment: Re: Chris_K. 
Not sure of the difference tbh. I'm hitting the moon button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a factor of how much memory you have but is also highly related to what you actually have running. On average my 4GB x64 box goes to sleep in between 30 seconds and a minute, but if I have VMware Workstation open (and busy) it can take around 10 minutes to fully sleep.

If it is actually sleeping and waking without any problems, I would not worry about this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It does nod off ok once it's finished preparing itself.

Comment: @Mr. Flibble, Thanks, +1... I see **SO MANY** problems relating to sleep and lock ups. If your machine is doing it fine, I would not tempt fate and try to tweak it.